# cront not working with hadoop command in shell script

Tags: shell, hadoop, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to schedule a cronjob using crontab to execute a shell script which executes a list of hadoop commands sequentially, but when i look at the hadoop folder the folders are not created or dropped. The hadoop connectivity on our cluster is pretty slow. so these hadoop command might take sometime to execute due to number of retries.

Cron expression

```
*/5 * * * * sh /test1/a/bin/ice.sh >> /test1/a/run.log
```

shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# == 1 ]
then
        TODAY=$1
else
        TODAY=`/bin/date +%m%d%Y%H%M%S`
fi

# define seed folder here
#filelist = "ls /test1/a/seeds/"

#for file in $filelist
for file in `/bin/ls /test1/a/seeds/`
do
        echo $file
        echo $TODAY
        INBOUND="hadoop fs -put /test1/a/seeds/$file /apps/hdmi-set/inbound/$file.$TODAY/$file"
        echo $INBOUND
        $INBOUND
        SEEDDONE="hadoop fs -put /test1/a/seedDone /apps/hdmi-set/inbound/$file.$TODAY/seedDone"
        echo $SEEDDONE
        $SEEDDONE
done

echo "hadoop Inbound folders created for job1 ..."
```

Comment: Are there any entries in the users mailbox that denote errors? Are the relevant path and environment variables configured such that they are available when the script runs? You'll probably need to amend the crontab to capture the stderr too: /test1/a/bin/ice.sh 2>&1  >> /test1/a/run.log

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no output that has been captured that could be used to debug the output, I can only speculate.

But from my past experience, one of the common reason hadoop jobs fail when they are spawned through scripts is that HADOOP_HOME is not available when these commands are executed.

Usually that is not the case when working directly from the terminal. Try adding the following to both ".bashrc" and ".bash_profile" or ".profile":

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
```

You may have to change the path based on your specific installation.

And yes as comment says, don't just redirect standard output but error too in the file.